# Adapter data mutableList crash when modified

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin

I'm making a SearchView Filter for a RecyclerView, in my Filter object, in the fun 'publishResults', my app crash because i'm trying to modify a mutableListOf, but the data.clear() and data.addAll() cause an error

Every modification to the list seems to make the app crash, I've never seen this error despite all other list I've tried to modify. I think the problem come from the fact that it's used by the recyclerView but I have no clue why, I've find nothing on internet and even less with kotlin language.
Also it seems like there is a big problem when trying to cast the `results?.values` to a Collection.

here is my full Adapter code

```
class SmallCatchAdapter(val clickListener: FishModelListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SmallCatchAdapter.ViewHolder>(), Filterable {

var data = mutableListOf<FishModel>()
    set(value) {
        field = value
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

var dataFull = listOf<FishModel>()

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    return ViewHolder.from(parent)
}

override fun getItemCount() = data.size

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = data[position]
    holder.bind(item, clickListener)
}

class ViewHolder private constructor(val binding: ItemListSmallCatchBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bind(item : FishModel, clickListener: FishModelListener) {
        binding.fishModel = item
        binding.clickListener = clickListener
        binding.executePendingBindings()
    }

    companion object{
        fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolder {
            val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            val binding = ItemListSmallCatchBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)

            return ViewHolder(binding)
        }
    }

}

override fun getFilter(): Filter {
    return fishListFilter
}

private val fishListFilter = object : Filter() {
    override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
        val dataFiltered = mutableListOf<FishModel>()
        if (constraint == null || constraint.isEmpty()) {
            dataFiltered.addAll(dataFull)
        } else {
            val filterPattern: String = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim()
            for (item in dataFull) {
                if(item.name.toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                    dataFiltered.add(item)
                }
            }
        }
        val results = FilterResults()
        results.values = dataFiltered
        return results
    }

    override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
        data.clear()
        data.addAll(results?.values as MutableList<FishModel>)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}

}

class FishModelListener(val clickListener: (fishModelId: Int) -> Unit) {
    fun onClick(fishModel: FishModel) = clickListener(fishModel.speciesID)

}
```

**Where it crashes**

```
override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
            data.clear()
            data.addAll(results?.values as Collection<FishModel>)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
```

The error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:161)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(AbstractList.java:374)
    at java.util.AbstractList.removeRange(AbstractList.java:571)
    at java.util.AbstractList.clear(AbstractList.java:234)
```

Everything worked well before i implement this functionality, now I've also noticed that this bug has somehow messed with my Room Query, one (and only one) of my coroutineScope is never launched, everythings else is ok

(Sorry for the mistakes, i'm not english)

Comment: can you share full code of recycvlerView ?

Comment: Change it to data.addAll(results?.values as MutableList<FishModel>)

Comment: @RahulKhurana `mutableListOf<FishModel>` will work for him i think

Comment: @Ashish I've add the full code of my adapter.

Comment: @RahulKhurana I've tried your proposition, unfortunatly i I can't tell if it work or not since the .clear() and .addAll also make the code crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using data inside `onBindViewHolder` you should create another list variable and use it

```
var filterList : mutableListOf<FishModel>()

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = filterList[position]
    holder.bind(item, clickListener)
}
```

For the filter I am showing some references, follow a similar way as below:

```
    private val customFilter: Filter = object : Filter() {
        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence): FilterResults {
            filterList =
                if (constraint.isEmpty()) {
                    items.toMutableList()
                } else {
                    items.filter {
                        it.name.contains(constraint, true) ||
                                it.name == constraint ||
                                it.price.toString() == constraint
                    }
                        .toMutableList()
                }

            if (sortByPV) {
                filterList.sortByDescending { it.pointValue }
            }

            return FilterResults().apply {
                values = filterList
                count = filterList.size
            }
        }

        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence, results: FilterResults) {
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

    override fun getFilter(): Filter = customFilter
    override fun getItemCount() = filterList.size
```

Here, you may need to update your code accordingly for item click listener.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I just don't know where does the "items" variable come from ? (in 'fun performFiltering' ) I'll try this and keep you updated

Comment: @Lyam.D `items` is the initial data list, In your code, I think it is `data`. `items`/`data` can be changed from fragment/activity by `recylcerAdapter.items = yourList`. After that you should also write `recyclerAdapter.filter.filter("defaultquerytext")`

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks a lot !
Had no need to change anything to the ItemClickListener so even better !
Still stuck with the couroutines context that has stopped working for black magic reason but this is for another time.