# Coroutine "withContext" is no more reach and read, stop working for no reason

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm using Architecture Components and Room but I don't think it come from there
I use coroutines to insert and retrieve data from the Database. Everything worked fine until I came to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56950335/adapter-data-mutablelist-crash-when-modified)

This last problem has been solved but he caused another problem. One of my coroutines to insert data was working fine before, and now the code inside `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {`  is never read. All the others function are working, and this one was too before. **The app doesn't crash,no error log, but the data is not inserted because withContext is never read**

I've tried rebuilding the project, relaunch Android Studio, reinstall the app but nothing made an effect, I've narrow down the bug to this few lines but I didn't find anything about that bug on the web, I've tried renaming it, passing it by another function but nothing, it's Black magic and I've no clue why it's stopped working suddenly like that, I did not even modify the code for the past week.

```
fun insertNewStats(sessionID: Long, fishSpeciesID: Int) {
        uiScope.launch {
            //This access to database is working fine
            val stats = checkDatabaseForStats(sessionID, fishSpeciesID)
            if (stats == null) {
                //This is the call of the function that is not working
                insertStatsToDatabase(sessionID, fishSpeciesID)
            } else {
                stats.numberOfCatch++
                updateStatsToDatabase(stats)
            }
        }
    }
```

this is checkDatabaseForStats, **if I put the insert here it will work perfectly**, meaning it doesn't come from the DAO function but from the withContext

```
private suspend fun checkDatabaseForStats(sessionID: Long, fishSpeciesID: Int) : SessionsFishStats?{
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val stats = database.getStat(sessionID, fishSpeciesID)
        stats
    }
}
```

**The part that doesn't work, the function is reached, not the *withContext***

```
private suspend fun insertStatsToDatabase(sessionID: Long, fishSpeciesID: Int) {
        //This function is reached, the code put there will be read and work
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            //And from there nothing, this code is never reached
            database.insertStats(
                SessionsFishStats(fk_sessionId = sessionID, fishSpeciesId = fishSpeciesID, numberOfCatch = 1L)
            )
        }
    }
```

This is the query in my DAO

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insertStats(stats: SessionsFishStats)
```

If i put the `withContext` directly in `insertNewStats` (not passing by a function) it will not work either

I want to remind that this code **used to worked perfectly fine** and stopped working when a non related bug occurred. The app doesn't crash, it's just code non read. **All the other Insert query in my app work, all the other withContext and DAO function work perfectly fine too**, it just this one that has been cursed for no reason other than black magic

---

I've done that, which is just put everything in the same function, and it worked perfectly fine. It's weird and I don't know why...

```
fun whyIsThisWorking(sessionID: Long, fishSpeciesID: Int) {
        uiScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val stat = database.getStat(sessionID, fishSpeciesID)
                if (stat == null) {
                    database.insertStat(
                        SessionsFishStats(fk_sessionId = sessionID, fishSpeciesId = fishSpeciesID, numberOfCatch = 1L)
                    )
                } else {
                    stat.numberOfCatch++
                    database.updateStats(stat)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add checkDatabaseForStats(sessionID, fishSpeciesID) code.

Comment: edited and added, but it's pretty straightforward, not sure it will be very usefull

Comment: Oh and the database.getStat is used in multiple others situation and work perfectly fine so i'm sure it's not from there

Comment: try making a Build and Clean of the project

Comment: Done a few times, didn't change nothing, I've even tried build the project without the DAO function and then rebuild it with, didn't worked either. Same after restarting Android Studio / The Computer

Comment: I've made an edit, I found a solution but I still don't understand why the previous way has stopped working suddenly